# Moving files with certain extension - C++

Tags: c++

this is my first time here on stackoverflow
so, what I want is a code to move certain extension from multiple folders into a specific folder
for example I have
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder4

each one has 2 files, one of them is txt and the other one is mp3
I want the code to create a new folder and move all the txt files and paste them into the new folder
like this:
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder4
folder5
so the txt files goes into folder5

any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi, have you tried something or just asking for code? :)

Comment: well, to be honest, I'm just a beginner, I only know some simple stuff about C++, that's why I'm here asking for help, tried reading books and watching videos, it didn't really help :/

Comment: "what I want is a code" - that isn't asking for help; that is requesting someone do it for you. I'm afraid that isn't how this site works. If you have a specific question about something [you have **tried**](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) we can help show the error of your ways. If you've tried something but it doesn't seem to work how you want, or work *as well* as you want, we can offer up ways to improve it. but "give me the codez" posts are generally closed in short-order. You may want to read the [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as well.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach would be using the [boost filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), which will provide every single function you will need and there is an [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html#Directory-iteration) that might lead the way.

To move a file using boost filesystem, you must use the [rename](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#rename) method

Comment: I took a quick look at this, and it's not clear how to move a file from one folder to another. If the files are in the same partition, Windows does the move by moving a directory entry (from one directory to another) without moving any file data.

Comment: Use the `rename` method, it will rely on the OS moving functionality (i.e., move only the directory entry in the filesystem, instead of moving the data)

Comment: Following rcgldr's comment, getting someone who is beginner in C++ (probably in programming too), to use Boost library is an overkill. If was the OP, I wouldn't even click on the link (if I knew what's behind that..)

Answer (score 0):

For windows, there's a move file function:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)